# How to add a comments section on android

Tags: android, comments

I have an android app that lets people create events. So when a registered member logs into the app, I want him/her to give the ability of commenting.

I do not want to integrate facebook commenting, because my app has a member registration/login system. So I want only the ones registered on my app to be able to add comments. I want to then send these comments to a database

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You should use something with Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab but my question is how to do it

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: @SuperThomasLab, it shows how to integrate GCM. And it says GCM is to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device, and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. I'm confused in how to use it to design a comments section on android